# Initialising a view controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

So my code works but I get a warning:

> Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument

Obviously this is because of the following line:

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithCoder:nil];
```

`MyViewController` is a `Swift` class. I have implemented the required `initWithCoder` method in it.

My question is simple - what parameter do I pass to `initWithCoder` to kill the warning or what alternate `init` strategy do I use?

*NB: The view controller I'm initialising is written in Swift. I am however initialising it from an Objective-c class.*

Comment: Your title and tag says `Swift`, while your code is `Objective-C`

Comment: Can you clarify this question a bit? You are stating that you initialize a view controller in Swift and present code showing an initialization using objective-c. In either case the docs state that init coder - "Returns an object initialized from data in a given unarchiver. (required)" You are not supplying the coder in your objective-c. You might also be getting an error related to the need to add @objc before your Swift class.

Comment: Made an edit to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it in a different way. If you use `storyboards`:

```
UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
```

If `storyboard` is different

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
```

Or from `xib`:

```
MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
```

Or if it is from code totally:

```
MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
```

Also remove `-initWithCoder:` method from your code

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The view controller is created in code (no Storyboard or Xib). Also, although the VC is written in Swift I need to launch it from Objective-c. How would your final solution be written in Objective-C? I've tried ```vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init]``` but I get a crash.

Comment: Which crash did you get?

Comment: I tried again and it worked when I also removed the initWithCoder method from my controller. If you update your answer to show that your final solution + remove the initWithCoder method from the VC works I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your view controller has no nib or storyboard you should not be using initWithCoder in Swift. Note this information from the UIViewController documentation:

**Discussion**

This is the designated initializer for this class.

The nib file you specify is not loaded right away. It is loaded the first time the view controller's view is accessed. If you want to perform additional initialization after the nib file is loaded, override the viewDidLoad method and perform your tasks there.

If you specify nil for the nibName parameter and you do not override the loadView method, the view controller searches for a nib file using other means. See nibName.

If your app uses a storyboard to define a view controller and its associated views, your app never initializes objects of that class directly. Instead, view controllers are either instantiated by the storyboard either automatically by iOS when a segue is triggered or programmatically when your app calls the storyboard object’s instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: method. When instantiating a view controller from a storyboard, iOS initializes the new view controller by calling its initWithCoder: method instead. iOS automatically sets the nibName property to a nib file stored inside the storyboard.

For more information about how a view controller loads its view, see Resource Management in View Controllers.

Here is what Resource Management says about initializing programmatically.

**Initializing View Controllers Programmatically**
If a view controller allocates its resources programmatically, create a custom initialization method that is specific to your view controller. This method should call the super class’s init method and then perform any class specific initialization.

In general, do not write complex initialization methods. Instead, implement a simple initialization method and then provide properties for clients of your view controller to configure its behaviors.